# Blog Posts are being identified as anti-banner

Tags: anti-virus, kaspersky

We have a blog post that is being identified by Kaspersky anti-banner as an ad so it is blocked.  However, there are no ads on the site. The article topic is what businesses should look for when they do any paid advertising.  (put link to post).  How do we get this false positive removed from the Kaspersky databases (the Kaspersky logs indicate that the page is blocked by database).